# Op levels for staff

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, server-administration

I've heard rumors that in 8.1+ you can set different op levels for different users. I have a new server, and I want to give staff members op level 3 so that they can kick and ban people if needed. Anything other than that is too much power, though. In the ops.json file I noticed that there's a level set for each op, but setting one to 3 doesn't seem to work, it's overwritten by the server.properties op level. ie. It stays listed as level: 3 for that user in ops.json but they're still able to use the /give and /tp command in game when  server.properties is set to 4.

Does anyone know of a way to set custom op levels, or a good way to allow /kick and /ban for staff members using command blocks somehow?

This is a Vanilla server, v1.8.7. (Took a few months to get it built and configured / and is marketed as vanilla, so I don't want to switch to bukkit, etc version).

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you can moderate this in the ops.json file of your server.

Go to your server's CraftBukkit, Spigot folder (or whatever its running). You should see the `ops.json` file. My Minecraft username is mukulibukuli and the way to put an op into the file is like this:

```
[ { "uuid": "22bfd181-b46d-4772-86d1-fc13ac7a09b2", "name": "mukulibukuli", "level": 1, "bypassesPlayerLimit": false } ]
```

The lower the level the higher permissions you get (lowest level is 1). You can find your UUID on namemc.com, enter your Minecraft username to find it.

I really wish they could add a <level> part of the "/op name". If it could look like "/op name, level" that would be awesome!

Comment: "This is a vanilla server"

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe this is fully implemented currently. If you want to set an OP level, it will have to be server-wide, via the config file. You can always use the server console to execute commands.

Sorry for the inconvenience, but that's just how it is for now. You said you dont want to switch to bukkit, but if you do, I would highly suggest PermissionsEX for controlling OP levels. It's a fantastic plugin if you spend a little time setting it up.